# Boxplots of different variables by cluster assigned on one graph in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I'm trying to figure out a way to plot the following code from base R in ggplot:

```
fit <- kmeans(iris[,-5], 3)

par(mfrow=c(1,4))
for (i in 1:4) {
  boxplot(iris[,i]~fit$cluster, xlab="Cluster",
  ylab=names(iris)[i], varwidth=T)
}
```

I have a hunch that there is a way to avoid using a loop to plot this in ggplot, but I don't know how.  So far, I only have one variable plotted.  What would I use to plot the boxplots by cluster for all the numeric variables?

```
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
comp.df <- cbind(iris, fit$cluster)
names(comp.df)[6] <- "cluster"

comp.df$cluster <- as.factor(comp.df$cluster)

test <- ggplot(comp.df, aes(x = cluster, y = Sepal.Length)) + 
  geom_boxplot()
```

Perhaps this is one of those instances where base r is better for plotting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this one should help

```
 library(reshape2)
 melted<- melt(comp.df[c(1:4,6)],id.vars="cluster")
 ggplot(melted, aes(x = cluster, y = value)) + 
     geom_boxplot()+facet_wrap(~variable)
```

The crucial element is **facet_wrap** which is similar to group by in SQL. Basically one plot is done per "variable". The melt command transforms your data from wide to long format. This means that the different characteristics are not longer columns, but that you have a value and a variable column

```
head(melted)



cluster     variable value
1       1 Sepal.Length   5.1
2       2 Sepal.Length   4.9
3       2 Sepal.Length   4.7
4       2 Sepal.Length   4.6
5       1 Sepal.Length   5.0
6       1 Sepal.Length   5.4
```

[image]

Comment: MLavoie, your solution is nice because it gives you more control of the formatting, as you mentioned.  But it would be cumbersome with more than 5 variables.  I like the solution by CAFEBABE, but wonder if there's a way to avoid reshaping the data.  My 7 mb dataset (100K rows) was reshaped pretty quickly into a 11 mb dataset (700K rows), but it would be nice to avoid this step if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You could reshape your data.frame to long form (here with `tidyr::gather`) and use `facet_grid`

```
library(tidyr)
comp.df.long <- gather(comp.df,key,value,-Species,-cluster)
ggplot(comp.df.long, aes(x = cluster, y = value)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_grid(.~key)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A bit longer and more manual, but there is also this simple way. Longer but it gives you more flexibility if you want to use different colors or sizes for each graph.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
test <- ggplot(comp.df, aes(x = cluster, y = Sepal.Length)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + theme_bw()

testb <- ggplot(comp.df, aes(x = cluster, y = Sepal.Width)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + theme_bw()

testc <- ggplot(comp.df, aes(x = cluster, y = Petal.Length)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + theme_bw()

testd <- ggplot(comp.df, aes(x = cluster, y = Petal.Width)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + theme_bw()
grid.arrange(test, testb, testc, testd, nrow=1)
```

[image]