# Create one boxplot per cluster for each column of information for a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, seaborn, boxplot

Let it be the following Python Panda DataFrame:

| value | other_value | cluster |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1382 | 2.1 | 0 |
| 10 | 3.9 | 1 |
| 104 | 5.9 | 1 |
| 82 | -1.1 | 0 |
| 100 | 0.9 | 2 |
| 1003 | 0.85 | 2 |
| 232 | 4.1 | 0 |
| 19 | 0.6 | 3 |
| 1434 | 0.3 | 3 |
| 23 | 1.6 | 3 |

Using the seaborn module, I want to display a set of boxplots for each column of values, showing the comparative information per value of the cluster column.

That is, for the above DataFrame, it would show a first graph for the 'value' column with 4 boxplots, one for each cluster value. The second graph would include information for the 'other_value' column also showing 1 boxplot for each cluster.

My idea is to do the same, but instead of in R language, in python: [Boxplots of different variables by cluster assigned on one graph in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34911746/boxplots-of-different-variables-by-cluster-assigned-on-one-graph-in-ggplot)

My code, It only shows the 1 to 1 graphs, I would like to get a joint graph with all graphs applied, as in the link above:

```
sns.boxplot(y='value', x='cluster',
                 data=df, 
                 palette="colorblind",
                 hue='cluster')
```

Thanks for the help offered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most seaborn functions work best with the data in ["long form"](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/data_structure.html#long-form-vs-wide-form-data).

Here is how the code could look like:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72301993/')[0]
df_long = df.melt(id_vars='cluster', value_vars=df.columns[:-1], var_name='variable', value_name='values')

sns.catplot(kind='box', data=df_long, 
            col='variable', y='values', x='cluster', hue='cluster', palette="colorblind", sharey=False, colwrap=2)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.catplot kind=box with long dataframe]

Comment: Nice trick with the read_html!